# null reference error in telerik Grid

Tags: controls, grid, telerik, rad

I always get a null reference error ( "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.") when try to edit a row in telerik rad control in runtime. I use asp ajax version.
Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method to get the data out of grid for each row:

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/calendar_serversideitemdatabound.html

I've run into problems like yours before too. It's weird because you can either access the column text or the Data that is being bound.